# Simple number sequence puzzle

Tags: lateral-thinking, number-sequence

Complete the sequence:

> 8, 6, 7, 3, 6, 5, 4, 5, 5, 2, ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think the missing member of the sequence is

> 6

Because

> These are the number of segments used to represent a number on a 7-segment display, counting backwards from 10, i.e, '10' requires 8 segments, '9' requires 6,..., '1' requires 2 and finally '0' requires **6**.

For reference

> [image]